# Can p4 submit succeed partially

Tags: submit, perforce

When p4 submit containing multiple files fails due to a conflict in a particular file, is any other file successful submitted to the remote depot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  This is the entire reason that changelists exist:

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.051/manuals/p4guide/07_changelists.html

> When you submit a changelist to the depot, the depot is updated atomically: either all of the files in the changelist are updated in the depot, or none of them are. This grouping of files as a single unit guarantees that all files grouped together in a changelist are updated simultaneously. A Perforce changelist is an atomic change transaction.